Dose Google in-app review work on Android TV?
I want to implement Google in-app reviews in my Android TV project. Based on the google document,

The in-app review only works on Android devices (phones and tablets) running Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher that have the Google Play Store installed.

The document was updated last year. I am wondering if people somehow get it to work on Android TV.
I followed the document to set the SDK and requested the review flow but got this error when running on Android TV:
com.google.android.play.core.review.internal.zzu: Failed to bind to the service
val reviewManager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(requireContext())
        reviewManager.requestReviewFlow().let {
            it.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "success")
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "failed: ${task.exception}")
                    // task.exception: com.google.android.play.core.review.internal.zzu: Failed to bind to the service
                }
            }
        }


